# How do I find the httpStatusCode via jQuery when submitting a $.POST form?

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, nginx, http-status-codes

I have made a simple HTML form which I want to post to FreshDesk (a ticket application). Once the form has been submitted via AJAX. I want to redirect the user to a page.

How do I return the HTTP Status codes and do conditionals with them?

```
var formData = new FormData(document.getElementsByName('fd_feedback_widget')[0]);// yourForm: form selector        
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://somedomain.freshdesk.com/widgets/feedback_widget",
        // where you wanna post
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorMessage) {
             console.log(errorMessage); // Optional
        },
        success: function(data) {


            if(statusCode==200){
                window.location="/thanks";
            }

        } 
});
```

The `statusCode` variable is what I am after. If I use `console.log(data)` it shows 200 OK in Firebug but the error I get is firstly, is does not redirect and secondly, Firebug spits out `(an empty string)`

I am using NGINX if that has any difference (https://serverfault.com/questions/196929/reply-with-200-from-nginx-config-without-serving-a-file)

Comment: did u try using the `statusCode` option in `ajax`? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) provides an option called `statusCode` which you can use to perform operations based on the statuscode you get. From the docs :

> An object of numeric HTTP codes and functions to be called when the response has the corresponding code. If the request is successful, the status code functions take the same parameters as the success callback; if it results in an error (including 3xx redirect), they take the same parameters as the error callback.

So, based on this, you could say that type of  the `statusCode` decides what function should be called next - the success or the error.

Here's how you'd do it :

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://somedomain.freshdesk.com/widgets/feedback_widget",
        // where you wanna post
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorMessage) {
             console.log(errorMessage); // Optional
        },
        statusCode: {
             404: function() {
                 alert("page not found");
             },
             200: function() {
                window.location="/thanks";
             }
        },
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { 
             //your code
        },
        error : function () {
        }


});
```

Comment: This works but it does not redirect - http://i.imgur.com/ciVRUT9.jpg that is what it does.. but it does not show the `(an empty string)` so it must be working - the redirect does not

Comment: maybe `window.location.href`?

Comment: Show us your console output

Comment: Try to put an alert instead of the redirect code and check if that alert gets triggered

Answer (score 0):

The status code is in the `status` property of the XHR object:

```
    ...
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorMessage) {
         console.log(jqXHR.status);
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        if(jqXHR.status==200){
            window.location="/thanks";
        }
    } 
    ...
```

Comment: What do you mean by error, I only see `200 OK`. Does the success event not fire?

Comment: Add a `console.log` to the beginning of the success event to see if it is firing

Comment: What does that mean? The event fired or didn't fire?